# How to display list item tags in a kodi skin

Tags: xbmc, kodi

I'm trying to customize the default Kodi skin 'estuary'. My plan is to display the tags of a movie next to the movie title.

The skin uses `$INFO[ListItem.Tag]` in the `DialogVideoInfo.xml` template file and Kodi displays the tags nicely when opening the video info screen.

But when I use the `$INFO[ListItem.Tag]` variable inside e.g. `MyVideoNav.xml` template nothing is displayed. Here's how I changed the default `MyVideoNav.xml` template

```
...
<control type="textbox">
    <left>30</left>
    <top>240</top>
    <width>525</width>
    <bottom>100</bottom>
    <visible>!ListItem.IsCollection</visible>
    <label>Tags: "$INFO[ListItem.Tag]"[CR][CR]$INFO[ListItem.Tagline,[I],[/I][CR][CR]]$INFO[ListItem.Plot][CR][CR]</label>
    <autoscroll delay="10000" time="3000" repeat="10000">Skin.HasSetting(autoscroll)</autoscroll>
</control>
...
```

No matter if the movie is assigned to a tag or not what I see is always `Tags: ""`

**Edit** You find the whole MyVideoNav.xml here: https://pastebin.com/dHqyQpHx. In line 52 you'll find my change.

Comment: Please mention which version of kodi you used!

Comment: `kodi --version` gives me `17.6 Git:20171114-a9a7a20 Media Center Kodi`

Comment: Ok then, replace tag property with label and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<label>$INFO[ListItem.Tagline]</label>` you need to create list item for `Tagline` first in `DialogVideoInfo.xml`

Add few lines in `DialogVideoInfo.xml` (for item-layout) after line no 306 :-

```
  <control type="label">
        <left>25</left>
        <width>214</width>
        <height>67</height>
        <top>245</top>
        <align>center</align>
        <aligny>center</aligny>
        <font>font12</font>
        <textcolor>grey</textcolor>
        <label>$INFO[ListItem.Tagline]</label>
    </control>
```

And Also after line no 360 :

```
<control type="label">
        <left>25</left>
        <width>214</width>
        <height>67</height>
        <top>245</top>
        <align>center</align>
        <aligny>center</aligny>
        <font>font12</font>
        <textcolor>grey</textcolor>
         <scroll>true</scroll>
        <label>$INFO[ListItem.Tagline]</label>
    </control>
```

NOTE: adjust Width and Height by yourself.
Now you can add and use `<label>$INFO[ListItem.Tagline]</label>` in `MyVideoNav.xml`

Hope this helps..!

Comment: Tested it but `$INFO[ListItem.Label2]` seems to contain the video rating

Comment: Please share the `MyVideoNav.xml` template content using pastebin

Comment: Edited the OP and attached the pastebin link

Comment: There is no list item created called Tagline in `skin.estuary`. for that  need to add few lines in `DialogVideoInfo.xml` so that you can use `tagline` listitem in `MyVideoNav.xml`. I have edited my answer

Comment: I don't want to use `Tagline` (Small Summary of current Video in a container ). What I want is to display the `Tag` (Will return the name of the 'tag' this movie is part of, See https://kodi.wiki/view/InfoLabels). As I mentioned in the OP `DialogVideoInfo.xml` successfully uses and displays tags.